# Cocos2d update method efficiency

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

In a fairly small game, I have everything updating (sprites, velocities,backgrounds ect.) in on large scheduled update method. I was wondering if there was a performance difference between just having one large scheduled update, or several ones only updating a couple sprites each?

I was also wondering if there a performance difference between:

```
    sprite.position = ccpAdd(sprite.postion, (delta*10, delta*5));
```

and

```
    sprite.position = ccp(sprite.position.x + delta*10, sprite.position.y + delta*5);
```

Is there a performance difference between assigning positions via ccp vs CGPointMake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None that matters.

If you really, really want to know, [measure it](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/11/depth-ios-cocos2d-performance-analysis-test-project/).

Those are minutiae. It's like asking if your car goes faster after waxing it. It might, it might not. In 99.99999% it simply doesn't matter because the difference is negligible and other contributing factors have much more weight (car: traffic and road conditions / game: drawing stuff on the screen).

Answer (score 0):

`ccpAdd` is resolved to `ccp` which is then resolved to `CGPointMake` so they are identical in your compiled code. They are all `#define` so it is done in the preprocessor.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, `ccpAdd` & `ccp` are identical in your compiled code.

As for your performance problem, if you have a lot of sprites to update you may want to spawn a background thread to do part of your updating there. 
[performSelectorInBackground:withObject:](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html) and don't forget to add the code in an [autorelease pool](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8631611/1270586)